# How do you flatten a sequence of assignments in a JavaScript AST?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, abstract-syntax-tree

Given this expression in JavaScript:

```
ipad[15] = opad[15] = some[12] = some[13] = undefined
```

I get this AST (from acornjs):

```
{
  "type": "Program",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "AssignmentExpression",
      "left": {
        "type": "MemberExpression",
        "object": {
          "type": "Identifier",
          "start": 3943,
          "end": 3947,
          "name": "ipad"
        },
        "property": {
          "type": "Literal",
          "start": 3948,
          "end": 3950,
          "value": 15,
          "raw": "15"
        },
        "computed": true
      },
      "right": {
        "type": "AssignmentExpression",
        "left": {
          "type": "MemberExpression",
          "object": {
            "type": "Identifier",
            "start": 3954,
            "end": 3958,
            "name": "opad"
          },
          "property": {
            "type": "Literal",
            "start": 3959,
            "end": 3961,
            "value": 15,
            "raw": "15"
          },
          "computed": true
        },
        "right": {
          "type": "AssignmentExpression",
          "left": {
            "type": "MemberExpression",
            "object": {
              "type": "Identifier",
              "start": 3965,
              "end": 3969,
              "name": "some"
            },
            "property": {
              "type": "Literal",
              "start": 3970,
              "end": 3972,
              "value": 12,
              "raw": "12"
            },
            "computed": true
          },
          "right": {
            "type": "AssignmentExpression",
            "left": {
              "type": "MemberExpression",
              "object": {
                "type": "Identifier",
                "start": 3976,
                "end": 3980,
                "name": "some"
              },
              "property": {
                "type": "Literal",
                "start": 3981,
                "end": 3983,
                "value": 13,
                "raw": "13"
              },
              "computed": true
            },
            "right": {
              "type": "Identifier",
              "start": 3987,
              "end": 3996,
              "name": "undefined"
            },
            "operator": "="
          },
          "operator": "="
        },
        "operator": "="
      },
      "operator": "="
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I convert this AST to something that when reserialized would produce:

```
ipad[15] = undefined
opad[15] = undefined
some[12] = undefined
some[13] = undefined
```

Basically, *flattening* the AST. How can it be done? I have been thinking about this for hours and trying to modify [this source code](https://github.com/lancejpollard/normalize-ast.js/blob/e5d06d98737154da86549ce0c3bdd1783251385f/index.js#L673-L700) to get it working, but it's a bit mind bending.

Each `AssignmentExpression` has a right property. So I feel like just setting them at the top level to the last right item would work, but it's for some reason eluding me.

I am logging in that `normalize_AssignmentExpression` function, and it is showing:

```
RIGHT Node { type: 'Identifier', start: 3987, end: 3996, name: 'undefined' }
RIGHT {
  type: 'AssignmentExpression',
  left: {
    type: 'MemberExpression',
    object: Node { type: 'Identifier', start: 3976, end: 3980, name: 'some' },
    property: Node {
      type: 'Literal',
      start: 3981,
      end: 3983,
      value: 13,
      raw: '13'
    },
    computed: true
  },
  right: Node {
    type: 'Identifier',
    start: 3987,
    end: 3996,
    name: 'undefined'
  },
  operator: '='
}
RIGHT {
  type: 'AssignmentExpression',
  left: {
    type: 'MemberExpression',
    object: Node { type: 'Identifier', start: 3965, end: 3969, name: 'some' },
    property: Node {
      type: 'Literal',
      start: 3970,
      end: 3972,
      value: 12,
      raw: '12'
    },
    computed: true
  },
  right: {
    type: 'AssignmentExpression',
    left: {
      type: 'MemberExpression',
      object: [Node],
      property: [Node],
      computed: true
    },
    right: Node {
      type: 'Identifier',
      start: 3987,
      end: 3996,
      name: 'undefined'
    },
    operator: '='
  },
  operator: '='
}
RIGHT {
  type: 'AssignmentExpression',
  left: {
    type: 'MemberExpression',
    object: Node { type: 'Identifier', start: 3954, end: 3958, name: 'opad' },
    property: Node {
      type: 'Literal',
      start: 3959,
      end: 3961,
      value: 15,
      raw: '15'
    },
    computed: true
  },
  right: {
    type: 'AssignmentExpression',
    left: {
      type: 'MemberExpression',
      object: [Node],
      property: [Node],
      computed: true
    },
    right: {
      type: 'AssignmentExpression',
      left: [Object],
      right: [Node],
      operator: '='
    },
    operator: '='
  },
  operator: '='
}
```

Not sure if that helps.

I try to make it like this, but it just outputs one:

```
function normalize_AssignmentExpression(node, scope) {
  const [left, leftExps] = normalizeProperty(node.type, 'left', node.left.type, node.left, scope)
  let [right, rightExps] = normalizeProperty(node.type, 'right', node.right.type, node.right, scope)
  const exps = [
    ...leftExps,
    ...rightExps
  ]

  let furthestRight = right
  while (furthestRight.type === 'AssignmentExpression') {
    furthestRight = furthestRight.right
  }

  if (left.type === 'ArrayPattern') {
    const assignments = []
    left.elements.forEach(el => {
      assignments.push(
        createAssignmentExpression(
          el,
          createMemberExpression(right, el),
          node.operator
        )
      )
    })

    return [
      assignments,
      exps
    ]
  } else {
    console.log('RIGHT', right)
    const assignment = createAssignmentExpression(left, furthestRight, node.operator)
    return [
      assignment,
      exps
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does it:

```
function normalize_AssignmentExpression(node, scope) {
  const [left, leftExps] = normalizeProperty(node.type, 'left', node.left.type, node.left, scope)
  let [right, rightExps] = normalizeProperty(node.type, 'right', node.right.type, node.right, scope)
  const exps = [
    ...leftExps,
    ...rightExps
  ]

  let furthestRight = Array.isArray(right) ? right[0] : right
  let rights = Array.isArray(right) ? right.slice(1) : []
  let lefts = [left]
  while (furthestRight.type === 'AssignmentExpression') {
    lefts.push(furthestRight.left)
    furthestRight = furthestRight.right
  }

  if (left.type === 'ArrayPattern') {
    const assignments = []
    left.elements.forEach(el => {
      assignments.push(
        createAssignmentExpression(
          el,
          createMemberExpression(right, el),
          node.operator
        )
      )
    })

    return [
      assignments,
      exps
    ]
  } else {
    const assignments = []
    lefts.forEach(l => {
      const assignment = createAssignmentExpression(l, furthestRight, node.operator)
      assignments.push(assignment)
    })
    assignments.push(...rights)
    return [
      assignments,
      exps
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw this when it was posted, but didn't have time to look at it, then the OP posted an answer that worked, and I ignored it.  But it was recently reopened by another answer, and I thought it interesting.  Here is one fairly clean solution:

```js
const getValue = (assignment) => 
  assignment .right .type == 'AssignmentExpression'
    ? getValue (assignment .right)
    : assignment .right

const handleExpression = (expression) => 
  expression.type === 'AssignmentExpression'
    ? [
        {...expression, right: getValue (expression)},
        ... handleExpression (expression .right)
      ]
    : expression

const process = (ast) => 
  ({...ast, body: ast .body .flatMap (handleExpression)})
  

const ast = {type: "Program", body: [{type: "AssignmentExpression", left: {type: "MemberExpression", object: {type: "Identifier", start: 3943, end: 3947, name: "ipad"}, property: {type: "Literal", start: 3948, end: 3950, value: 15, raw: "15"}, computed: true}, right: {type: "AssignmentExpression", left: {type: "MemberExpression", object: {type: "Identifier", start: 3954, end: 3958, name: "opad"}, property: {type: "Literal", start: 3959, end: 3961, value: 15, raw: "15"}, computed: true}, right: {type: "AssignmentExpression", left: {type: "MemberExpression", object: {type: "Identifier", start: 3965, end: 3969, name: "some"}, property: {type: "Literal", start: 3970, end: 3972, value: 12, raw: "12"}, computed: true}, right: {type: "AssignmentExpression", left: {type: "MemberExpression", object: {type: "Identifier", start: 3976, end: 3980, name: "some"}, property: {type: "Literal", start: 3981, end: 3983, value: 13, raw: "13"}, computed: true}, right: {type: "Identifier", start: 3987, end: 3996, name: "undefined"}, operator: "="}, operator: "="}, operator: "="}, operator: "="}]}

console .log (JSON.stringify (process (ast), null, 2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

`getValue` traverses down the list of nested Assignment expressions until it finds something other than an `AssignmentExpression`  for `right`, and returns it.

`handleExpression` takes an expression and returns an array of expressions, either the original, or, if the type is `AssignmentExpression`, then a flattened list of this sort of chain.  There is some inefficiency here in recalculating `getValue` for the nested nodes.  I don't know how much work it would be to get rid of this.

`process` is probably throw-away code, to demonstrate in this simple document.  You would have to determine how to apply `handleExpression`.

For instance, when I ran Acorn against the sample, I got an extra layer of `ExpressionStatement` wrapped around the `AssignmentExpression`, and needed something more like this:

```js
const process = (ast) => ({
  ...ast, 
  body: ast .body .flatMap (
    (expr) => expr .type == 'ExpressionStatement' ? handleExpression (expr .expression) : expr
  )
})
```

This does not attempt to deal with `start` and `end` nodes.  It will now get them wrong, and it's probably worth removing them.  (Rewriting them correctly would be a huge task, I imagine.)

---

Finally, are you sure this is how you want to process these nodes?  It strikes me that you might also have to deal with something like:

```js
ipad[15] = opad[15] = some[12] = some[13] = someTimeConsumingFunction()
```

and you wouldn't want this to become

```js
ipad[15] = someTimeConsumingFunction()
opad[15] = someTimeConsumingFunction()
some[12] = someTimeConsumingFunction()
some[13] = someTimeConsumingFunction()
```

Instead, I personally would prefer:

```js
some[13] = someTimeConsumingFunction()
some[12] = some[13]
opad[15] = some[12]
ipad[15] = opad[12]
```

And this could probably be done by a version like this, which doesn't need the `getValue` helper:

```js
const handleExpression = (expression) => 
  expression.type === 'AssignmentExpression'
    ? [... handleExpression (expression .right), {...expression, right: expression .right .left}]
    : expression
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simplest possible transformation using [`Putout`](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout) code transformer I'm working on, it's not scalable for infinite assignments, but good for simple cases like one from example :

```js
module.exports.replace = () => ({
    '__a = __b = __c = __d = __e': `{
        __a = __e;
        __b = __e;
        __c = __e;
        __d = __e;
    }`
});
```

It looks this way:

[image]

You can try it in [`Putout Editor`](https://putout.cloudcmd.io/#/gist/5ecb300edc5dc998a670b2c6d37c9df6/5987ff458d9e6dbe538a19832b01bc779d0737c6).

To remove nested blocks use [@putout/plugin-remove-nested-blocks](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/master/packages/plugin-remove-nested-blocks#putoutplugin-remove-nested-blocks-):

```js
import putout from 'putout';

putout('ipad[15] = opad[15] = some[12] = some[13] = undefined', {
    plugins: [
        'remove-nested-blocks',
        ['flatten-sequence-assignment', {
            report: () => 'flatten assignments',
            replace: () => ({
                '__a = __b = __c = __d = __e': `{
                     __a = __e;
                     __b = __e;
                     __c = __e;
                     __d = __e;
                }`
            }),
        }]
    ]
});
```

Comment: Two things.  First, it's considered good form if you're promoting the use of a tool you're responsible for to add some sort of disclaimer.  "...using Putout code transformer (note: I am the founder of this project)", or some such.  Second, the question was pretty clearly generic.  Would you expect to write a different version for six chained assignments?  What about for thirty-seven?  How does this scale?

Comment: Thank you, I added clarifications. About generic question, totally disagree. If you want to show generic task you will definitely wright: a1 = a2 = ... = aN, or something like this. In question there is no word about generic.

Comment: Thank you for adding that.  About generic code, only the OP knows for sure, but as the sample code and the accepted self-answer are both written in a generic fashion, I would assume this is not meant specifically for those variables, nor for exactly four chained assignments.  Still, I look forward to looking over putout.